# Cannot play Media on physical device android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer

I write an app to play a mp3 file. When I run the app on the Emulator, it work well. But when I run it on my LG V10, the app got crash. Here is my code:

```
playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
MediaPlayer mp3Player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_1);
```

When I the user click button Play, it will call this function:

```
public void clickPlay(View view){
    if(mp3Player .isPlaying()){
        mp3Player .pause();
    }
    else
        mp3Player .start();
}
```

I don't know what problem there. Pls help.

Comment: post error log also.

Comment: Please post `logcat` output

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happen. But when i re-install my Android studio. it work well .

Thanks you guys.